# Printing a simple sudoku board array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

So my code is currently missing the 8th index of the array and pushing it down 1 row. I'm new to kotlin but I honestly have no clue why its doing that.

```
fun main() {
    val board = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0),
        arrayOf(6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9),
        arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8),
        arrayOf(0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0),
        arrayOf(0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0),
        arrayOf(9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5),
        arrayOf(0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2),
        arrayOf(1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0),
        arrayOf(0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7)
    )
    for (row in 0 until board.size) {
        if(row % 3 == 0 && row != 0) {
        println(" - - - - - - - - - " )
        }
            for(col in 0 until board.size) {
               if(col == 8){
                    println(" ")
                }
                if(col % 3 == 0 && col != 0) {
                print(" |")
                }
                print(" ")
                print(board[row][col])
            }
    }
}
```

With the output being

```
7 8 0 | 4 0 0 | 1 2 
 0 6 0 0 | 0 7 5 | 0 0 
 9 0 0 0 | 6 0 1 | 0 7 
 8 - - - - - - - - - 
 0 0 7 | 0 4 0 | 2 6 
 0 0 0 1 | 0 5 0 | 9 3 
 0 9 0 4 | 0 6 0 | 0 0 
 5 - - - - - - - - - 
 0 7 0 | 3 0 0 | 0 1 
 2 1 2 0 | 0 0 7 | 4 0 
 0 0 4 9 | 2 0 6 | 0 0 
 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works flawlessly according to your requirement (as you wanted trailing spaces before and after)

**Code:**

```
val board = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0),
    arrayOf(6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0),
    arrayOf(9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5),
    arrayOf(0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2),
    arrayOf(1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0),
    arrayOf(0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7)
)
for (row in board.indices) {
    if (row % 3 == 0 && row != 0) {
        println(" - - - - - - - - - - - ")
    }

    for (col in board.indices) {
        if (col % 3 == 0 && col != 0) {
            print(" |")
        }
        print(" " + board[row][col])
    }
    println()
}
```

**Result:**

```
 7 8 0 | 4 0 0 | 1 2 0 
 6 0 0 | 0 7 5 | 0 0 9 
 0 0 0 | 6 0 1 | 0 7 8 
 - - - - - - - - - - - 
 0 0 7 | 0 4 0 | 2 6 0 
 0 0 1 | 0 5 0 | 9 3 0 
 9 0 4 | 0 6 0 | 0 0 5 
 - - - - - - - - - - - 
 0 7 0 | 3 0 0 | 0 1 2 
 1 2 0 | 0 0 7 | 4 0 0 
 0 4 9 | 2 0 6 | 0 0 7
```

**Edit:** `<>.indices` is just a short extension for `0 until <>.size`

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a new line inside the inner for loop which is actually required after it. I've modified your code as follows:

```
for (row in 0 until board.size) {
    if(row % 3 == 0 && row != 0) {
        println(" - - - - - - - - - " )
    }
    for(col in 0 until board.size) {
        if(col % 3 == 0 && col != 0) {
            print(" |")
        }
        print(" " +board[row][col])
    }
    println()
}
```